# Как получать уведомления (обновления данных) даже когда приложение закрыто?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Пример. Вот есть Вконтакте, которое отправляет уведомления о сообщении, даже когда приложение закрыто.
Я подумал, что можно реализовать через `Service`, но так как их изменили (приложение закрывается и система их убивает) - не вариант. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Возможно эти 3 простых русских слова помогут: Firebase Cloud Messaging

Comment: @VladVetrov, а если я пользуюсь другой базой данных? Или это не имеет значения?

Comment: Это просто название такое, вот ссылка: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/

Comment: @VladVetrov, Спасибо большое